# How to pass laravel validation error count in java script variable

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, validation, laravel-9

I want to get Laravel validation error count value into the javascript variable and notify to the user to you have missout the required number to the user using sweet alert. how does the pass error count to js variable?

```
{{ $errors->count() }}
```

this error count needs to pass the js variable.laravel errors will generate after the submission .how do i get this value using JS or Jquery.i try following way it not work to me.

```
$("#btn-submit").click(function(event) {
    var error_count = "<?php echo $errors->count(); ?>";
    alert(error_count);

});
```

Comment: laravel error will produce after the submission of the form .you can not get error from `$("#btn-submit").click(function(event)`

Answer (score 1):

***Note: `$errors->count()` works/activate after you submit the `form` request***. If you need to get the count afterwards, you can do it like this

```
@if($errors->count())
    <script>
        alert( {{$errors->count()}} );
    </script>
@endif
```

> If you wish to show the error count before submitting, you might have to `AJAX` or some [frontend validation javascript libraries](https://www.jqueryscript.net/blog/best-form-validation.html)

Answer (score 0):

the  tag can't compile blade templating syntax. Instead of using blade

```
{{ $errors->count() }}
```

you can try with php tags with echo and htmlspecialchars

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($errors->count()) ?>
```

Try:

```
var error_count =  <?php echo htmlspecialchars($errors->count()) ?>;
```

Comment: i try before but it is  not work

Comment: `var error_count = "<?php echo $errors->count(); ?>";`

Comment: it should something like that in PHP .but in laravel it not going to work

Comment: How about assign it to variable first and use htmlspecialchars() ?

Comment: it always returns 0 not correct error count